# Playing all sound from one device to another

Tags: applications, sync, bluetooth, audio, streaming

Let me explain my situation first. I have a tablet that is connected to a Bluetooth device that is connected to my auxiliary of my car speakers. I can only connect one device at a time. I have a tablet in the back of my car that my customers, as an Uber driver, can use to listen to their own preferred music or media. It's too complicated to switch back and forth each time I pick up a passenger.

I tried solving this by getting a auxiliary spliter. So when the customer in the back starts playing their music, all I have to do is turn my music off and we can hear their music or media. Otherwise both of our music plays simultaneously.

I could deal with that but there is a static interference from using the splitter, which I can't seem to eliminate, unless I manually disconnect the splitter. Interference seems to come from having two devices connect to one line, even if one device is not having any sound output. I can disconnect any one of the two devices and the static interference goes away, so it's not the splitter itself in question.

So without installing some manual switch to switch back and forth to keep from having a cross connection interference, I'm trying to find an app that works kind of like Spotify new connection does. Where I can play audio from my back tablet and it plays through my front tablet.

After a bit of research, I come across a lot of apps that come close but not exactly how I need it to. I need to make it convenient for the customer because they tend to shy away from making me feel uncomfortable in my vehicle.

Preferably I would like my back tablet to take over the sound of my front tablet. So even if I'm playing music on my front tablet and someone starts the tablet in the back it will turn my sound off and start playing through my tablet in the front which has a constant connection to my Bluetooth.

Anybody know a way that I can accomplish this even if not the way I intended originally. If not a app maybe a specific Bluetooth device that will allow one device precedence over another without having to manually switch back and forth. Or maybe something that I haven't even thought of.

By the way I have SureLock installed on the tablet in the back. So whatever suggestions you might come up with it has to be able to run through that.

Thank you for your help and I appreciate any suggestions you might offer.

Comment: Nobody can offer a suggestion to my dilemma?